# Get HTML from browser's view-source functionality using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Is it possible to somehow get HTML code into Javascript string by using browser's functionality *view-source*:

```
view-source:http://www.google.com
```

I'm trying with code like this one, but I get errors about document not being defined:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
```

I know cross-domain requests aren't possible, unless using some sort of hack, but this looks much easier although it's very difficult to fetch the code. I DON'T want to visit website to prevent images and CSS loading.

Comment: in firefox yes, in chrome and IE no. ex:: window.open("view-source:data:text/html,"+escape(document.body.outerHTML));

Comment: @dandavis can you please be more precise? I still get error about document not being defined

Comment: show me the code that produces the error and i can hazard a guess.

Comment: window.location.href = 'view-source:https://www.google.com/';

Comment: anything I try after that causes error, just need to copy displayed code to JS string

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read data from another domain unless it cooperates with you.

If you do have that cooperation, you can simply send a CORS AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it in firefox. it doesn't work anywhere else afaik. 
for simplicity i used alert() and sync "ajax", but with any ajax lib, an async version would be trivial.

the main thing is getting firefox's nice view-source html back, which indicates line numbers, HTML errors, and markups html sections like attribs and content into semantic wrappers. it's the only way i know to validate html inside the browser without an internet connection...

```
// sync url fetcher function:
function IO(a){var b=new XMLHttpRequest;b.open("GET",a,!1);b.send();return b.responseText}

// create a new iframe to show the source code:
var fr=document.createElement("iframe");

// when it loads, let's view it using a simple alert()
fr.onload=function(){
  alert(win.document.documentElement.outerHTML);
  document.body.removeChild(fr);
};

// now add the frame into the document:
document.body.appendChild(fr);

// now assign the view-source url to the frame to trigger it's onload()
url= "/"; //just use site's home page for this demo
fr.src="view-source:data:text/html,"+escape( IO( url ) );
```

oh, and of course, this will only work for urls on your domain or that are setup with cors.

Answer (score 0):

Works in Chrome and Firefox. Safari assumed. IE untested.

```
document.querySelector('html').innerHTML
```

*Edit I think your error is coming from somewhere else. That statement, while clumsy, is perfectly valid.

If you're getting errors about document not being defined, then you're executing this before the document object is ready (are you waiting for DOMREADY or load?) or its executing outside a DOM interface (web worker?).

Comment: document is not defined!

Comment: Don't get snappy with people trying to help you.

Comment: I'm using Imacros to run this script

Comment: Is this the iOpus product?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to use IMacros next to JS to fetch HTML, doesn't help. I will need IMacros in later script so I'm using JS inside it

Comment: Ok this is your problem. The code snippet I provided and the one you had works. The question you need to be asking is how to access the document object from inside your iMacros product. I can't help you with that.